# SAS Input: Dollar Amounts in Billions

Tags: sas

I have an input file with a lot of dollar amounts given like this:

```
$433.5B   $41.1B   $331.1B   $407.4B
$110.8B     $19B $2,265.8B   $170.1B
```

where the `'B'` character stands for "billions". I do not have other suffixes like `M` or `k`. I need to read in this file using an `INPUT` statement in SAS inside a `DATA` step, and these figures should be numerics. There are several challenges to overcome, as well as a couple of features of the data to note:

1. There are dollar signs everywhere.
2. Some of the numbers have decimal points, and some don't, so we're dealing with variable-length data.
3. There are commas inside the numbers, such as `$2,265.8B`.
4. The most pesky aspect of this data are the `B`'s after each amount.
5. The `B`'s are always in the same columns.

   > What informat should I use to read in this numerical data?

I thought of using something along the lines of `:DOLLAR4.1`, like this:

```
Data bigcompanies;
    Infile 'path\bigcompanies.dat' MISSOVER;
    Input (sales profits assets market_value) (:DOLLAR4.1);
Run;
```

but it gives me nothing (as in, I get periods for those numbers). I don't know how to handle the `B`, which is, I think, the crux of the problem. The SAS documentation on the `DOLLAR` informat is rather sparse, unfortunately.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are there other B's on the data line for non dollar variables that need to be kept?  Do you need to handle values using other suffixes (M, K, etc)?

Comment: You said the B's are in fixed places. Are all of the fields actually in fixed locations, not delimited? Make sure to look at the file using a non-proportional font, like Courier.

Comment: There could be other `B`'s on the same line, but they would be in text fields and I can handle them already with column input as character variables. I don't need other suffixes like `M` or `k`.

Comment: Yes, I'm viewing the data file using a fixed-width font, and the `B`'s are always in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in fixed columns then just skip the columns where the `B` appears.

```
data test;
  input sales dollar6. +1 profits dollar8. +1 assets dollar9. +1 market_value dollar9. +1 ;
*---+---10----+---20----+---30----+---40 ;
cards;
$433.5B   $41.1B   $331.1B   $407.4B
$110.8B     $19B $2,265.8B   $170.1B
;

proc print;
run;
```

Results

```
                                     market_
Obs    sales    profits    assets     value

 1     433.5      41.1      331.1     407.4
 2     110.8      19.0     2265.8     170.1
```

Note that you normally never want to add a decimal part to an informat. That is telling SAS where to place the decimal point when it does not appear in the source text.  So "integers" will be divided by that power of 10.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!